# PHP: Create an array for a range

Tags: php, arrays, variables, numbers, range

If I have a variable `$num = 50` how can I put the numbers 1-50 into an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be solved by using a simple [for](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) loop:

```
//  Start ↓    End ↓  Step ↓
for ($i = 1; $i <= $num; ++$i) {
    $array[] = $i;
}
```

Answer (score 53):

Take a look at the [range](http://php.net/range) function.

```
$array = range(1, $num);
```

Answer (score 11):

Have a look at the documentation for the [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function:

```
<?php

    $array = range(1, 50);

?>
```