# Create array with natural numbers from 1 to a given number with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: fill an array with numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775344/php-fill-an-array-with-numbers)

I'd like code a PHP function that creates an array with natural numbers from 1 to a given number and I have not a clue of how to do this.

e.g : if I give the function the natural number 3 then the array should be 1,2,3 ; if I give the function the integer 2 1,2 ; if 5 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: as the key or the value?

Comment: Please look at the [list of array functions in the PHP Manual](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) before asking superfluous questions. It's a completely pointless and worthless exercise to have people link you to the appropriate manual pages here. Also see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple

Comment: @webbiedave You're right webbiedave I've voted to close my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is already a function that will do this: [`range`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php).

```
range(1, 3); // array(1, 2, 3)
range(2, 5); // array(2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: Thanks I'd never heard of this function !

Answer (score 2):

Use `range()` :

```
$array = range(1, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just look at this http://ua.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php